# Unwanted autocomplete suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm getting unwanted autocomplete suggestions and I'm not sure how to disable them.

**Example of suggestions**

[image]

**Path of which the suggestions are pulled**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts`

**settings.json (part)**

```
  "files.exclude": {
    "/**/node_modules": true,
    "/**/bower_components": true,
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    ".vscode": true
  },
```

Any ideas to disable this would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

`RTCIceCandidatePairChangedEvent` is a dom type. Dom typing suggestions are included by default for JS and TS, along with types for the the standard JavaScript library.

To explicitly control which typings are included, create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) file that sets `lib`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "lib": ["es6"]
     }
}
```

The above config means that only the `es6` standard library typings will be included. [Here's more info on the `lib` setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: Thanks this helps, I'll test a few hours to make sure I'm not missing something :)